# Add function with parameters in smarty variable

Tags: php, function, smarty, prestashop

I'm a prestashop developper and i want to add my custom function using parameters in a smarty variable.
There's my PHP function

```
function maFonctionSMarty($params)
    {
        $array['1'] = $params['monParametre'];
        $array['2'] = $params['monParametre1'];
        return $array;
    }
```

and in m'y template i try to do this

```
{$a|maFonctionSMarty:"toto":"tata"}
```

and i have an error.

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'SmartyCompilerException' with message 'Syntax Error in template &quot;/Users/guillaume/Sites/prestashop_156/modules/wb_newsletter/admin_panel.tpl&quot; on line 94 &quot;{$a|maFonctionSMarty:&quot;toto&quot;:&quot;tata&quot;}&quot; unknown modifier &quot;maFonctionSMarty&quot;' in /Users/guillaume/Sites/prestashop_156/tools/smarty/sysplugins/smarty_internal_templatecompilerbase.php:667 Stack trace: #0 /Users/guillaume/Sites/prestashop_156/tools/smarty/sysplugins/smarty_internal_compile_private_modifier.php(132): Smarty_Internal_TemplateCompilerBase->trigger_template_error('unknown modifie...', 94) #1 /Users/guillaume/Sites/prestashop_156/tools/smarty/sysplugins/smarty_internal_templatecompilerbase.php(475): Smarty_Internal_Compile_Private_Modifier->compile(Array, Object(Smarty_Internal_SmartyTemplateCompiler), Array, NULL, NULL) #2 /Users/guillaume/Sites/prestashop_156/tools/smarty/sysplugins/smarty_internal_templatecompilerbase.php(259): Smarty_Internal_TemplateCompilerBase->callTagCompil in /Users/guillaume/Sites/prestashop_156/tools/smarty/sysplugins/smarty_internal_templatecompilerbase.php on line 667
[PrestaShop] Fatal error in module smarty_internal_templatecompilerbase:
Uncaught exception 'SmartyCompilerException' with message 'Syntax Error in template "/Users/guillaume/Sites/prestashop_156/modules/wb_newsletter/admin_panel.tpl" on line 94 "{$a|maFonctionSMarty:"toto":"tata"}" unknown modifier "maFonctionSMarty"' in /Users/guillaume/Sites/prestashop_156/tools/smarty/sysplugins/smarty_internal_templatecompilerbase.php:667 Stack trace: #0 /Users/guillaume/Sites/prestashop_156/tools/smarty/sysplugins/smarty_internal_compile_private_modifier.php(132): Smarty_Internal_TemplateCompilerBase->trigger_template_error('unknown modifie...', 94) #1 /Users/guillaume/Sites/prestashop_156/tools/smarty/sysplugins/smarty_internal_templatecompilerbase.php(475): Smarty_Internal_Compile_Private_Modifier->compile(Array, Object(Smarty_Internal_SmartyTemplateCompiler), Array, NULL, NULL) #2 /Users/guillaume/Sites/prestashop_156/tools/smarty/sysplugins/smarty_internal_templatecompilerbase.php(259): Smarty_Internal_TemplateCompilerBase->callTagCompil
```

thanks

Comment: Isn't your function accepting only one param

Comment: What's your error exactly ?

Comment: That's not your exact error. Copy/paste it please.

Comment: i wrote it in the post. Thnaks for your Help

Comment: You could create a custom smarty plugin? http://www.smarty.net/best_practices

Comment: You have to register your smarty function in order to be able to use it. http://www.velvetblues.com/web-development-blog/smarty-templates-create-custom-functions/

Answer (score 0):

You have to put that function as a plugin in a separate file named modifier.maFonctionSMarty.php in tools/smarty/plugins. Also, the name of the function has to be different:

```
function smarty_modifier_maFonctionSMarty($params)
```